# fscanf file read in matlab for mixed numeric and non-numeric data (textscan not available)

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to read a data file but I have an older version of Matlab that does not include  textscan.  I am trying to use fscanf but I am unable to figure out how to read the second  element which is time format.  The txt data looks like this:

20120502,16:30:00,1397.5,1397.5,1397.0,1397.5,1283
20120502,16:32:00,1397.25,1397.5,1397.0,1397.0,582

I have tried this, with different attempts at figuring out the 2nd column which is the time  vector, but I am not having any luck.

```
fid = fopen('C:\matlab\data\GLOBEX.txt','r');  
[c] = fscanf(fid, '%f %s %f %f %f %f %f');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[c] = fscanf(fid, '%f,%d:%d:%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f');  
c = reshape(c, 9, length(c)/9)';
```

Now you have hours, minutes, and seconds in columns 2, 3, and 4.